# How to prove that each matrix "C" switched with A is diagonal

Tags: matrices

```
    [1 0 0]
A = [0 2 0]
    [0 0 3]

    [1 1  1]
B = [0 2 -1]
    [0 0  1]
```

That's my matrix and now I have an exercise where I have to prove that each C matrix switched with A is diagonal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how exactly to translated 'switched' from my language, but it's something like "commute" in my language.

Comment: You mean $CAC^{-1}$?

Comment: @ user117293  So is the question then to show that $[A, C] = AC - CA$ is diagonal?  Perhaps it would help if you presented the idea of "switched" in algebraic, formulaic terms, like $[A, C] = AC - CA$ is diagonal or $CAC^{-1}$ is diagonal or whatever.

Comment: My guess: If $AB=BA$ then $B$ is diagonal.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, there is no equation, it's only text. That's why it confuses me. Also, I am not given the matrix C, I have only matrix A and B.

Comment: @ user117293:  then what is $B$?

Comment: Whatever the language is, there *must* be somewhere a definition using not only words. Put it, otherwise not even you are sure what is "switching"...

Comment: @RobertLewis Added B.

Comment: @ user117923:  indeed you did!  But how does it relate to the question? As such, we've got a standalone definition with no obvious relation to $A$ or $C$.  Getting there, though . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis So should I take matrix C with random values or the same values as A and prove that AC - CA is diagonal?

Comment: @user117293:  I don't know, I'm still trying to figure out how $B$ relates to $A$, asssuming it does, and what "switched" means.  Sorry I can't be more helpful, but in all sincerity, Merry Christmas anyway!

Comment: @user117293 can you look in your textbook to see if they have a definition of your word "switched"?  Otherwise, can you post the word so that somebody might recognize it?  You never know what other languages people on this website speak

Comment: @RobertLewis Maybe you can replace 'switched' with 'cummute' and understand it better. Anyway, I posted B as you requested, I don't think it's anyhow connected to this question anyway. Merry Christmas to you as well and everyone else! :-)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "комутира" (komutira) if anyone knows the proper term in English, feel free to correct me.

Comment: That seems to be bulgarian (commutation, according to google translate), or perhaps any other language with cyrillic alphabet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiplying a matrix by $A$ from one side multiplies the rows of the matrix by 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Multiplying from the other side does the same with the columns.

Comment: Could you show me how it's done with equations or what should I prove? Because I'm kinda lost right now.

Comment: Write out the matrix $B$ in full, with entries $b_{11}$, $b_{12}$, $b_{13}$, $b_{21}$, …, $b_{33}$, compute the products $AB$ and $BA$, and compare entry by entry. You will see a pattern in the two products (the content of my hint).